# Submit gcp ai-platform training job with network/subnetwork tags?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I would like to have access to certain databases (not in gcp) in my network when running a training job. How can I specify the subnet or network tags when the training instance is spun up?

Comment: What are the subnet tags used for?

Comment: Have access to on prem resources

Comment: We now support VPC Peering with your VPC, which in theory could access your on-prem resource if you have connected on-prem network with your VPC. VPC Peering is in alpha now. Can you send us an email via cloudml-feedback@google.com if you want to give a try please?